# What does "over ride" mean from an Objective-C Standpoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, overriding

While hearing talk around the objective-c programming community, I hear the term "override" thrown around a lot.  I'm fairly familiar with general object oriented programming terms, but from an iOS and Objective-c standpoint, the definition is a little unclear to me. According to Wikipedia:

> Method overriding, in object oriented programming, is a language
>   feature that allows a subclass or child class to provide a specific
>   implementation of a method that is already provided by one of its
>   superclasses or parent classes.

Cool. That makes sense. But what throws me off is... isn't that the whole point of the "family relationship", where the subclass inherits all of the public methods and variables of it's superclass. The standard "hierarchy" model. That has never quite made sense to me. I hear some of the senior developers say things such as "Once he said it's okay to override a category I was done listening".

That got me to thinking, I should probably get a better grasp on what exactly overriding is. Could someone explain it in greater detail related specifically to Objective-C / Cocoa Touch?

Comment: At least for Objc, you can specifically re-write the code for methods that are automatically taken care for you. For example, a `UIViewController` explicitly has a `loadView` method that you should never actually call to load a view controller's view. _But_ you can override it to customize and create your views manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very common in all OOP languages.

Often times a base class will provide a *default* (i.e. simple, unexciting) implementation for a method. Then, derived classes will **override** that default implementation and provide a *specific* (i.e. more interesting) implementation.

Consider an `Animal` base class that exposes a `Speak()` method. Well there is no common way that animals speak, so that default implementation would probably just do nothing.

A `Dog` class, which is derived from `Animal`, can **override** `Speak()` to actually make a barking sound, which is more appropriate than the default mute case.

Answer (score 1):

Your quote from your senior seems to me like it's mis-heard or -remembered. I'd bet it was "...it's okay to override a method **in a** category I was done..."

Using a category to "override" a method *on the same class* is a Bad Idea: the original method is clobbered and cannot be called. In addition, if the original method was itself implemented in a category, then which version is actually used [is undefined](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4). This is *not* the same as overriding an inherited method (thus my scare quotes).

Overriding an inherited method works as expected: a class defines a method which was already defined in one of its ancestors. When the method is called on an instance of the subclass, the redefined code is run. The class itself can invoke the non-overridden version by using the `super` keyword as the receiver of the appropriate message.